# Libgdx Creating multiple animation

Tags: animation, libgdx

How to create multiple animation in libgdx? eg: I have created animation of moving bird when i click on the bird how to create another animation of falling bird..

Answer (score 0):

Look at the libgdx Sprite Animation tutorial:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteAnimation

After a 'click' you'll need to switch from using your "moving bird" animation sheet to using a "falling bird" animation sheet.

Or are you asking about actually creating the falling bird animation sheet in the first place?

Comment: I already created animation of moving bird but actually I want to create multiple instance of bird using hashmap technique and also want to create the animation of falling bird when ever gdx.input.justTouched() event called.